# Can C# 9.0 records support data structures like dictionaries and lists?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, immutability

I've seen several examples of the new records feature in C# 9.0. I.e., being able to update individual properties to create new immutable records. What I'm curious to know is if the `with` syntax allows me to insert new entries into something like a dictionary, creating a new immutable dictionary along with all the sibling properties that make up the record.

For example, can I do something like this?

```
public record Person
{
    public string Name;
}
 
public record Car
{
    public string Model;
    public Dictionary<string, Person> Riders;
}

var car = new Car 
{
    Model = "Delorean",
    Riders = ("driver", new Person { Name = "Doc Brown" })
};

var newCar = car with
{ 
    Riders with ("passenger1", new Person { Name = "Marty McFly" })
};
```

Comment: FWIW I think it is a valid question, but the answer is "not really". You could perhaps consider the immutable collection APIs where Add etc are functions not methods (meaning: they return a different collection, they don't change the existing one)

Comment: Can you please explain the tuple-like syntax you're using above? It doesn't seem to be valid C# to me, even in C# 9. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835232/can-c-sharp-9-0-records-support-data-structures-like-dictionaries-and-lists#comment114632370_64835232), for sure you can't do this because `with` works with record types only. But it's also not entirely clear what you mean anyway. The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class isn't immutable to start with, so `with` doesn't seems necessary. What do you expect the proposed syntax above to do?

If you mean for it to *replace* the dictionary contents, you can do that with the current `with` syntax easily:

```cs
var newCar = car with
{
    Riders = new Dictionary<string, Person> { { "passenger1", new Person { Name = "Marty McFly" } } }
};
```

If you mean to *add* to the existing dictionary contents, but with a new instance, that's not quite as elegant, but is still easy and seems almost as nice to me:

```cs
var newCar2 = car with
{
    Riders = new Dictionary<string, Person>(car.Riders)
    {
        { "passenger1", new Person { Name = "Marty McFly" } }
    }
};
```

Are you hoping for something that avoids the `new Dictionary...` part? I do not believe that's possible in the current version of C#, even with all the enhancements that have been made over the past few versions to support collection initializers.